# How to delete saved credit card numbers of completed orders from Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, credit-card, magento-1.9

We are using saved cc for our website.We want to flush saved credit card information of completed orders.Can anyone help to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Finally I created a custom extension to do this.Magento stores CC information in sales_flat_order_payment and sales_flat_quote_payment.I extended order grid class and added a custom action and controller.

```
`$updatefirsttable = "UPDATE `sales_flat_order_payment` SET `cc_number_enc` = NULL,`cc_exp_month`=NULL,`cc_exp_year`=NULL,`cc_type`=NULL WHERE `entity_id` =$transactions->entity_id";
$updatesecondtable = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_payment` SET `cc_number_enc` = NULL,`cc_exp_month`=NULL,`cc_exp_year`=NULL,`cc_type`=NULL WHERE `quote_id` =$transactions->quote_id";`
```

Comment: Here is a link of My Extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/24232/

Comment: This answer is life saver.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
    <form method="GET">
    <?php 
      if (isset($_REQUEST['beforeDate'])) { 
        $beforeDate = $_REQUEST['beforeDate'];
      } else { 
        $beforeDate = date("d.m.Y", time() - 24*60*60*30);  
      } 
      if (isset($_REQUEST['submitFlag'])) { 
        if ($_REQUEST['submitFlag'] == 1) { 
          $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "<login>", "<password>", "<database>");
          $result = $mysqli->query("
    update 
      sales_flat_order_payment p 
    set 
      cc_number_enc = null   
    where  
      cc_number_enc is not null
      and 
      entity_id in 
      ( 
      select
        entity_id
      from  
        sales_flat_order ord  
      where 
        ord.created_at <= date '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($beforeDate)) . "'    
      ) 
          ");
          if ($result){
            echo "<h2>Credit card information deleted till $beforeDate. Affected records=" . $mysqli->affected_rows . "</h2>";
          } else {
            echo "There's an error processing your request: please, contact developer: <your email>";
          } 
        }   
      } 
    ?>
    <label for="beforeDate">Please, enter date, before which you would like to delete credit card information<label>
    <input type="text" name="beforeDate" id="beforeDate" value="<?=$beforeDate?>"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Let's do it!"></input>
    <input name="submitFlag" type="hidden" value="1"></input>
    </form>

    </html>
```

Comment: Works for me with this PHP script. Do not forget to close it from others  :)